# Ajax Combobox can no longer find TextBox control after update 1.4.609

Tags: c#, ajax, combobox, controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I was using the old version of Ajax (1.4.5...) and after upgrading to 1.4.609.. my ajax combobox code is throwing a nullreference error. I think it's now having trouble finding TextBox control portion of the combobox, but I'm not sure. Has anyone else had this problem? and more importantly, has anyone found a solution for it? Here is the code:

```
public Unit LocationCellWidth
    {
        get { return ComboBoxCell.Width; }
        set 
        {
            ComboBoxCell.Width = value;

   error------> ((TextBox)LocationComboBox.FindControl("TextBox")).Width = value;             
               //LocationComboBox.Width = value;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late then never, I just had the same issue.

The control name has changed to:
"SelectCategoryCombo_TextBox"

inspecting the combobox object in the debugger gives you the above ID for the textbox control.

so:

```
TextBox comboTextBox = LocationComboBox.FindControl("SelectCategoryCombo_TextBox") as TextBox
```